# there is + icon even for leaf nodes in rich tree jsf2.0

Tags: jsf-2, tree, richfaces

I am getting default plus(+) icon in richTree even for nodes which has no child under it. The plus icon vanishes once you click on it. I need that plus icon not to come for the leaf node i.e. the nodes which has no childs.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="productComponentTree">
                <rich:tree id="pcTree" var="pcTreeNode" >
                    <rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor id="recTreeAdaptorID" 
                        roots="#{productComponentBean.productComponentList}"
                        nodes="#{pcTreeNode.financialServicesAgreementComponent}">
                        <rich:treeNode  id="treeNodeID" expanded="true"  icon="#{item.toShow?item.icon:'null'}">
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="treeNodeCheckBox"
                                disabled="#{productComponentBean.disabledCheckBox}"
                                value="#{pcTreeNode.selectedFlag}"
                                onclick="checkUncheckNodes(this);">
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            <h:outputText value="#{pcTreeNode.name}"></h:outputText>
                        </rich:treeNode>
                    </rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor>
                </rich:tree>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
```

above is the code for tree. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really simple.

Just add to treeModelRecursiveAdaptor the `leaf` tag.

```
<rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor id="recTreeAdaptorID" 
                    roots="#{productComponentBean.productComponentList}"
                    nodes="#{pcTreeNode.financialServicesAgreementComponent}"
                    leaf="#{isLeaf(pcTreeNode)}">
```

With:

```
public Boolean isLeaf(Node node){
    return (node!=null && (node.children==null || node.children.size()==0));
}
```